# No SystemOutOfMemoryException

Tags: crash, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory

My App suddenly crashes at one point (reproducible) when run on a 512mb phone emulator (only have a 920 to test). There wasn't any exception, it just went black. I then ran the analysis tool on the application and found out the memory reaches its limit at the point the app crashed. The app exits with an error code. The most recent one I found was 0x887a0005, but I'm pretty sure I saw another one a little time back. Sadly, I don't have that one anywhere.

I load about 600 images from the web into BitmapImages with the CreateBackground option, and handle the ImageOpened event.

I'm not asking for help managing the problem itself, I'll find a way to work around it. I'm just wondering why the App isn't throwing any exceptions, and instead just crashes. Any ideas her

Comment: You could implement something like Little Watson to record any of these unhandled exceptions (even if one isn't thrown to you when you're debugging, I bet there is one). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx. I use this in one of my apps and it works extremely well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Depending on which piece of code is executing at the very moment you run out of memory, an out of memory exception may be thrown - if one can be thrown by that specific .NET class or under laying class. But the operating system is not going to wait for this to happen, and will usually just terminate your app. It's not sending your app a "terminate" or "out of memory" signal, it just kills it.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that was the expected behavior.